# In D3.JS, where is the data located after d3.selection.data(myData)?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Suppose I have something like this...

```
var myData = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; 
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg"); 
var initializeData = svg.selectAll("rect").data(myData);
```

Where is the data (myData) stored in the object initializeData? I can't find it anywhere. It must have a reference to the data somewhere if the method enter() uses the data in myData.

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the [source of data()](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/selection/data.js), it's quite confusing but from what I can tell, it's storing the data in a variable within the scope of the function.

This means it's not publicly available as a property of the object returned (update), but can still be used in the functions inside update as they are closures which have access to the enclosing scope.

This is really the best I can explain it without getting too much into closures and exactly how the data function works.

Comment: Isn't that after he calls enter() though? I'm asking about before that.

Comment: Oh okay, that's a good explanation (although I'm not too too acquainted with  closures). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To add to @JosephYoung answer, yes it's storing it in a closure created within the `enter()` function.  With your example code above if you `console.log(initializeData)`, you can inspect this:

[image]

Comment: Didn't know you could view the closures within Chrome's console, very cool

Answer (score 0):

The data is actually bound to the DOM element. For instance, if you bound a bunch of circles you can actually run

```
d3.selectAll('.circle')
  .each(function(d) { ... access element data .. });
```

I use this when doing post-rendering. You can do the save thing with events with `.on( function(d) { ...d is element data ..})`

Comment: This if there are circle elements to be bound to. I'm talking about the case where there are no current circle elements, and append() needs to be called after enter(). It's just weird that initializeData (in the OP) can call enter() and generate placeholder elements, but the initializeData object seemingly doesn't have any (visible) reference to it when I inspect it.